# Admin area is caching posts in the editor

Tags: cache

I recently updated to WP 5.3.1

And now, when I create a new post, it mixes up with previous posts.

Also, when I reload the post list index in the WP admin area, it will not display the last published post until I hit reload a few times.

Something that bothers me a lot is, that when I publish one post, and then create a new one, it will update the last post instead of creating a new one.

This seems to be a cache-related issue, but I am not sure and maybe it is a bug in the new version.

I use the WP Super Cache plugin, but as far as I know, it does not affect the admin area, only the public side of the site.

I asked my hosting provider if they are doing some extra cache, but they are not.

I also recently added `Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"` to my .htaccess file (but I removed that). Do you think that might be causing the problem?

What else might be happening?

Comment: It can, if you configure it incorrectly. You can also have some caching mechanisms on your server...

Comment: If you're setting cache control headers for pages under `wp-admin` then your browser will cache those pages, you should stop that or add exclusions

Comment: @TomJNowell Thanks, I thought it only affects images. It's strange that caches even the post slug and the textarea contents. I will remove it completely and see if that fixes the issue.